# only get specific childs in Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

```
{
  "chat" : {
    "-JZvOzp0L1ccuBt2TVN7" : {
      "author" : "JavaUser21221",
      "message" : "hello "
    },
    "-JZvPneW5et0_EVRvL5g" : {
      "author" : "JavaUser21221",
      "message" : "hai"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to only get the messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in that data structure. When you read a tree in Firebase, you get all the children.

If you want just the messages, you'd have to maintain a separate data structure, [which is easy using mutli-path updates](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html).

```
{
   "chatMessages": {
      "-JZvOzp0L1ccuBt2TVN7": "hello",
      "-JZvPneW5et0_EVRvL5g": "hai"
   }
}
```

Then you can sync all just the children:

```
var ref = new Firebase("<my-firebase-app>");
var messagesRef = ref.child("chatMessages");
messagesRef.on("value", (data) => console.log(data));
```